# Compilation error in magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

Class Webkul\Marketplace\Helper\Data does not exist
Class Webkul\MobikulMp\Controller\Seller\RewriteUrlPost\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not
generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/mage
nto setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested cla
ss did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related constr
uct method, only.

How to fix the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will help you but I do it in the following way

```
sudo php bin/magento s:up
sudo php bin/magento s:d:c
sudo php bin/magento s:s:d -f
sudo php bin/magento c:f
```

after all I use

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<user-group> .
```

so that browser can also read and write

on was a server I believe sudo chown -R www-data:www-data . is use for server side as user and user group

Happy coding